# Jacobi and Gauss iterative methods

Tags: python, iteration, numerical-methods

I'm writing iterative solvers of linear systems and I run into the problem of `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`
I'm unsure what the problem is as I've gotten them to work without OverflowError before (albeit wrong solutions).

Code:

`

```
def Jacobi(A_in,x0_in,b_in,tol,step_max):
    N=len(A_in)
    x0=x0_in
    b=b_in
    it=0
    A=A_in.copy()
    x1=np.copy(x0)
    while 1:
        for i in range(0,N):
            S=0.0
            for j in range(0,N):
                if i!=j:
                    S+=(A[i][j]*x0[j])   <-- Either I'm wrong about formulation here
            x1[i]=(b[i]-S)/A[i][i]       <-- Or it's to do with how Python treats my copies...?       
        dist_x0_x1=0
        for i in range(N):                  #Distance between x0 and x1
            dist_x0_x1+=(x0[i]-x1[i])**2
        dist_x0_x1=np.sqrt(dist_x0_x1)
        print(f"kth iteration:{x1}")
        if (dist_x0_x1)<tol:
            return x1
        else:
            x0=np.copy(x1)
            it+=1
        if it>step_max:
            print("Diverging")
            break



A1=np.array([[2,4,-2,-2],[1,2,4,-3],[-3,-3,8,-2],[-1,1,6,-3]])
b1=np.array([4,-3,5,1])
```

`

Code below produces a slightly different error:
`

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
  dist+=(x0[d]-x_g[d])**2
```

`

`and:`

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  dist=(dist)**0.5
```

`

`

```
def GaussSeidel(A_in,x0,b_in,tol=1E-5,max_step=100):
    b=b_in.copy()
    AC=A_in.copy()
    N=len(A_in)
    it=0
    x_g=np.copy(x0)
    while(1):
        for i in range(0,N):
            S=0.0
            for j in range(0,N):
                if i==j:
                    continue
                else:
                    S+=AC[i][j]*x0[j]
            x0[i]=(b[i]-S)/AC[i][i]

        dist=0
        for d in range(N):
            dist+=(x0[d]-x_g[d])**2

        dist=(dist)**0.5

        if dist<tol:            
            return x0
        else:
            x_g=np.copy(x0)
            it+=1
        if it>max_step:
            print("Divergent")
            break



 A=np.array([[2.0,4.0,-2.0,-2.0],[1.0,2.0,4.0,-3.0],[-3.0,-3.0,8.0,-2.0],     [-1.0,1.0,6.0,-3.0]],dtype="f")
b1=np.array([4.0,-3.0,5.0,1.0])
```

`

I've tried changing the location of initialization of S thinking it would impact the run by avoiding recursive explosion. I've changed the formulation of dist several times and made sure it produces the results I need. I've tried to change the way the program copies the input matrix, solution vector and x0 initial guesses to prevent inaccuracies or incompatability with the syntax in the loops but I'm at a loss!

Comment: Your main problem is that `A` is not diagonally dominant, and drastically so in the first two rows. This means that the iterations will diverge. This is then met with a data type mismatch, explicitly setting `dtype=float` can help with this secondary problem.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I originally had dtype=float defining my array earlier but results didn't seem to change when I changed it.

Comment: As I said, the divergence is independent of the data type, the data type only changes the iteration count at which the error occurs.

Comment: Right okay. 
At the moment the code seems to completely ignore the attempt at finding a value at all.
It gives the following: 
0:th iteration iteration:[ 1 -1  2  2]
1:th iteration iteration:[2 0 1 1]
2:th iteration iteration:[1 0 1 0]
3:th iteration iteration:[0 0 1 0]
4:th iteration iteration:[0 0 0 0]
5:th iteration iteration:[0 0 0 0]
------
Could it be that I've screwed up the iteration-formula or that it's struggling with data type conversion or something like that?

Comment: Dear lord I changed the initial guess vector (excluded from the code I posted) to float values and it worked immediately. 
Thank you @LutzLehmann for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: The error message was telling you that Python was using BigInts ! When solving a linear system, this is in general wrong.